# Обращение к элементу двумерного массива

Tags: java

Вопрос может показаться детским, но я не смог найти на него ответ. Имеется двумерный массив строк.

```
String[][] arr = {{Anna, Nicol, Peter}, {Sara, Gary, Emmy}, {Alex, Den, 
Gloria}
```

Как обратиться к конкретеому элементу массива используя цикл?
Например,

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++){
  for(int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j ++){
    какой-то код для обращения к конкретному элементу
    System.out.print( хочу вывести случайный элемент 
    каждого подмассива);
  }
 // Output: Peter, Sara, Alex - используя функцию Random   
}
```

Заранее благодарю.

Comment: у второго цикла лимит должен быть `j<arr[i].length`, тогда доступ  к элементу `arr[i][j]`

Comment: @Serodv я описался) бывает, но вопрос не в этом. При таком выводе выводятся все элементы массива, а мне надо, чтобы выводилось по 1- му элементу каждого подмассива

Comment: тогда убираете внутренний цикл и формируете второй индекс через рандом Random.nextInt（arr[i] .length-1)

Comment: @Serodv спасибо огромное,  только не понимаю, зачем длину цикла уменьшать на единицу?

Comment: Потому что максимальный индекс массива = массив.длина - 1

Comment: @ArchDemon, уменьшать на 1 не надо, вот спека:  
nextInt(int bound)
Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (**exclusive**), drawn from this random number generator's sequence.

Comment: Да, вы правы, единицу не надо вычитать.

Answer (score 0):

1. Вы используете при инициализации массива Anna, Nicol, Peter без кавычек. Компилятор считает их идентификаторами.

Приведу пример кода с обращением к "конкретному" элементу массива по порядку:

```
    /*
 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/848931/Обращение-к-элементу-двумерного-массива
 */
package stringByIndex;

/**
 *
 * @author vvm
 */
public class StringByIndex {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] arr = {{"Anna", "Nicol", "Peter"}, {"Sara", "Gary", "Emmy"}, {"Alex", "Den",
            "Gloria"}};
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(arr[i][j] + " "); // обращение к конкретному элементу по индексу
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Вывод программы:

```
run:
Anna Nicol Peter Sara Gary Emmy Alex Den Gloria
```

Comment: Теперь, когда вы вывели элементы по порядку, вы сможете обратиться к ним случайным образом по индексу. Но не совсем случайному. Ваш генератор случайного индекса должен быть в пределах размерности массива. Иначе вы можете выйти за границы массива и получите исключение:  'ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException'